# Image src won't change using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, src

I feel like I have this right, but for some reason, the addEventListener isn't functioning how I want it to. When I try to change the img.src below, it still only shows the 'images/expand.jpeg' img.
I have confirmed that the path to the image is correct, as it does show the 'images/collapse.png' when I change the button's original src to 'images/collapse.png'.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.title').forEach(function(){
    let button = document.createElement('img');
    button.classList.add('smallbutton');
    button.src = "images/expand.jpeg"; 
    eachTitleDiv.append(button);
    button.addEventListener('click', function(){
        if (button.src === "images/expand.jpeg") {
            button.src = "images/collapse.png";
        } else if (button.src === "images/collapse.png") {
            button.src = "images/expand.jpeg";
        };
    });
});
```

Comment: Might not have access to the button variable when the click event fires, especially since it changes for each loop iteration. Use e.target instead

Comment: Have You Tried Using `==` instead of `===` in the if statement?

Comment: @ZachJensz That unfortunately didn't fix it.

Comment: @mrtechtroid just tried it, it didn't do anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Relative src attribute computes to absolute URL in the DOM

1. When you access the `src` attribute, it's the computed DOM value, and your relative link was computing to the absolute link. `(https://yourwebsite.com/images/expand.jpeg === "images/expand.jpeg")` returns *false*
2. ALWAYS have an `alt` on your images, like in this case where they don't load, for visually impaired, SEO so many reasons!

Here is a working snippet where the `alt` is used to check state rather than the `src`:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.title').forEach(function(eachTitleDiv){
    let button = document.createElement('img');
    button.classList.add('smallbutton');
    button.src = "images/expand.jpeg";
    button.alt = "expand"
    eachTitleDiv.append(button);
    button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        if (button.alt === "expand") {
            button.src = "images/collapse.png";
            button.alt = "collapse"
        } else if (button.alt === "collapse") {
            button.src = "images/expand.jpeg";
            button.alt = "expand"
        };
    });
});
```

```html
<h1 class="title">Title 1</h1>
<h2 class="title">Title 2</h2>
<p>Not a title</p>
```

Comment: As it turns out the event listener *does* have access to `button`, I learned something too haha

Comment: Hello, It is recommended that you use debugger to help you debug when writing code.